# All the toasters close when clicked on the close button in react

Tags: reactjs

I have made a toaster component of my own which on multiple clicks render multiple toasters. The problem I am facing is that all the toasters are terminated when the handle close component is clicked or when the settimeout function is called. I am passing messages through another component as props.

This is my toaster component

```
export default class MyToaster extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: props.message,
            show: false,
            no: 0
        };
    }
    handleclose = () => {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
            no: this.state.no - 1
        })
    }
    handleOpen = () => {
        console.log('HANDLE OPEN')
        this.setState({
            show: true,
            no: this.state.no + 1
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    show: false,
                    no: this.state.no - 1
                })
            }, 3000)
        })

    }

    createtoaster = () => {

        if (this.state.show) {
            let toastmessage = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.no; i++) {

                let tmessage = <div className="snackbar">
                    <div className="card-header">
                        <h3 className="card-title">Toast</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div className="card-body">
                        {this.state.message}
                    </div>

                    <div className="card-footer"></div>
                    <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleclose}>x</button>
                </div>
                toastmessage.push(tmessage);

            }
            return toastmessage;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-9">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleOpen}></button>
                {this.createtoaster()}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried managing the state in the parent component but it doesnt seem to work. I do know that the problem is in managing state of my toaster component but  dont know the exact problem and the solution.
Any solutions for this also feel free to point out any of my mistakes.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different way to this approach.

```
export default class MyToaster extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: props.message,
            show: true,
            no: 0
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({show: false})
        }, 4000)
    }

    handleclose = () => {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
            no: this.state.no - 1
        })
    }

    handleOpen = () => {

        this.setState({
            no: this.state.no + 1
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    show: false,
                    no: this.state.no - 1
                })
            }, 3000)
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-9">

                {this.state.show
                    ? (
                        <div className="container snackbar" style={this.props.style}>

                            <div className="card-header">
                                <h3 className="card-title">Toast</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div className="card-body">
                                {this.props.message}
                            </div>

                            <div className="card-footer"></div>

                        </div>
                    )
                    : null
}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

And from your parent component you can include

```
this.state = {
toasterCollection: []
}

//make a function
handleToasterClick = () => {
        const toaster = <Toaster message={this.message} style={this.style}/>
        this.setState({
            // toasterCollection: [...this.state.toasterCollection, toaster]
            toasterCollection: [...this.state.toasterCollection, toaster]
        });
    }

//In your Render give a button
 <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleToasterClick}>
                Toast
            </button>
//Also render this
 {this.state.toasterCollection}
```

This should get your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

Handle close is run on the click of any button rather on the instance of one of them by the looks of it.

```
if (this.state.show) { // this determines whether to render you toasts... 
                       // and close turns all of them off.
```

You need to change each toast to have it's own show property and for close to toggle that one and remove it from the array of toasts to generate.

Note:

Your props and state should be separate, don't copy props into state as this will introduce bugs and changes will not be reflected.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // avoid copying props into state
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor
    this.state = {
        message: props.message,
        show: false,
        no: 0
    };
}
```